# Ways to utilise java thread to perform concurrent execution

Tags: java, concurrency

During the exam I had following question:
"What is a Java thread and how are multiple threads handled by a single
processor core?
[2 marks]

(a) Describe the two ways in which a class may utilise a thread to
   perform concurrent execution. [6 marks]

(b) How does Java’s synchronized keyword help with concurrent thread
     execution? [2 marks]"

Could anyone make a respond to point a?
I wrote that by calling this thread's start() method and by passing this thread to executor? Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since it looks like beginner stuff, I would probably go with "subclassing `Thread`" and "implementing `Runnable` and passing that to a `Thread`".

Comment: (+1) Impossible to be sure without knowing what they've been taught, but I like your thinking.

Comment: Also, it's a bit weird that they ask how a "__class__ may utilise a thread", so they probably are looking for Thread and Runnable.